# How to get the index value of a TextField defined in table

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a table view in which I'm showing some text fields. My problem is I want to read the data from those text fields. I am able to get the value but I want to know which text box the value is from, ie I want the index of the text box.

Comment: Is your textfield in a custom cell?  Where are you implementing the delegate protocol methods?

Comment: Do you have multiple text fields per cell?

Answer (score 0):

you can use UITabeViewCell's index... it would be same... 
you can get it

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    //row is your index
```

Answer (score 0):

Textfields within a tableviewcell do not have index values because they are not part of the table itself but are merely ordinary subviews of the tableviewcell's content view.

Therefore, you access them just like you would any subview. The tableviewcell's content view is the textfields superview.

If you use one of the standard tableviewcell styles, then you can easily access them by name e.g. `myTableViewCell.displayLabel.text`. If you have custom cell class you can make references the textfields properties of the class and access them by property name.